# What's the Literal translation of these basic words?

Tags: hebrew

What do the words Mishnayos, Gemara, & Torah literally mean?

Comment: Why don't you check it on WIKI first? Is that something that WIKI doesn't answer?

Comment: Did you mean to ask about the etymologies of these names?

Comment: Partial dupe: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101546/

Answer (score 5):

- *Mishna* (plural: *mishnayot*): "study by repetition", from the verb *shanah* שנה ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishnah))
- *Gemara*: from the Aramaic verb *gamar*, study ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemara))
- *Torah*: "Instruction", "Teaching" or "Law" ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torah))

Comment: Good explanations. There is a nuance that "Torah" also means "guidance", but, I think that nuance is somewhat implied by the definition of "instruction".